# mysqli insert into function not returning true or false

Tags: php, mysqli

Hey there first time poster here. I'm creating a registration form using php and mysqli, and everything is working fine up until the actual insert function.

I've checked and double checked and triple checked the variable names within the query, they are correct, the form inputs are reaching the function as well, but for some reason at £this->connect->query($query) it refuses to work. I've tried countless different ways to execute the actual query, each one returning false. I'm at my wits end here, hopefully someone can help!

```
function insertNewRecord($fname, $lname, $pass, $email, $mob, $school, $location, $connumb)
{
    $query = "INSERT INTO 'dbusers' 
        (firstName, lastName, password, emailaddress, mobnumb, school, campus, connumb) 
VALUES ($fname, $lname, $pass, $email, $mob, $school, $location, $connumb)";
    if(!$this->connection->query($query)) {
        echo $query;
    }
}
```

edit: I figured it out, I forgot to auto_increment the userid within the table. I've been stuck on this for hours, I feel like such an idiot.

Thanks for your time

---

Comment: Have you tried using mysqli_error() to see if it reports anything?

Comment: The query will probably not run without errors, because `password` is a keyword in MySQL, so you need to encaps it in "`" (backticks) also, string and data values need to be encapsed in single or double quotes.

Comment: additionally, the $values should be in "'". Otherwise they are interpreted as field names (and produce errors if they contain spaces)

Comment: The values should be quoted but you really should be using a prepared statement with bound variables.

Answer (score 1):

Try using your query in the following form:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `dbusers` 
        (`firstName`, `lastName`, `password`, `emailaddress`, `mobnumb`, `school`, `campus`, `connumb`) 
VALUES ('$fname','$lname', '$pass', '$email', '$mob', '$school', '$location', '$connumb')";
```

But this is not the correct way to go, you should use prepared statements to prevent SQL injection. See [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php)

Comment: Just tried this, unfortunately it didn't work. Thank you for the response though. :)

Comment: It straight up didn't respond. When I clicked the submit button, the page flickers but doesn't go to the correct page afterwards, because the insert function isn't returning as true.

Comment: This breaks on strings containing the `'` character, you would need to use `mysqli_real_escape_string` on all variables. But prepared statements is the way to go.